# Using side effects in control flow

Tags: javascript

Is it considered bad practice to have side effects in an `if` statement? For example, something like this:

```js
'use strict';
let a = 2;
if ( a++ > 2) {
    // ...
}
```

Or:

```js
'use strict';
let a = 2;
if ( a++ > 2, a) {
    // ...
}
```

Or:

```js
'use strict';
let a = 2;
if ( ++a > 2 && a++) {
    // ...
}
```

If so, why would that be frowned upon, and what might be a better approach?

Comment: It's not terribly common, and usually more confusing than alternatives, but occasionally it's the best approach. Best example was before `.matchAll` and we had to do `while (match = re.exec(str)) {` for global regular expressions with capture groups. If you find non-native code that seems to require something like this, do your best to refactor it to something less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is considered as a bad practice *by some* (me included). There are linter rules to avoid this convention.

Why?

Because it's less readable. You want a single instruction to perform a single action. `a++` vs `++a` not only does something in expression (which can already be considered clumsy), but also doesn't seem to be easiest to read. I always need to think for a moment whether the value returned is `a` or `a + 1`.